# Working on multiple terminals

Tags: terminal

I am using ubuntu terminal for my project and at times I need more than 5 terminals to be open at the same time and kind of juggle between them to see outputs of multiple programs running simultaneously. I am having hard time toggling between the terminals. Is there something that will hold all terminals together in one window and make my life simpler? I read somewhere that  konsole does that for me, but I cannot bring up konsole for some reason and I am getting an error : bash: konsole: command not found.

Any kind of info/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: tmux  .......................

Comment: Emil - I am on it, right now..

Comment: @William : Does tmux splits one window into multiple just like emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try Konsole, try installing it first. It's part of KDE if that helps.

http://konsole.kde.org/

Ubuntu comes with gnome iirc. It has gnome-terminal as jasonspiro pointed out.

Comment: I am having hard time getting konsole source from the website, could you please help me with that?

Comment: I cannot use apt-get as I am working on a remote server where I will have to download source and build it, I do not have permissions to use apt-get

Comment: I do not have any experience doing that. Sorry.

Comment: I am using konsole on my machine and ssh from there. I am loving it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `tmux` (and eventually, `tmuxinator`). It may have a slight learning curve but it'll be worth it, once you have it mastered!

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYcsU.png)'s what an example session looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Use gnome-terminal instead.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop indicates to me that it comes with Ubuntu.  It lets you open multiple tabs.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or click the appropriate menu command to open a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using multiple workspaces? I'm using ubuntu 11 and if I find that I have a terminal layout I like to keep intact I simply place all of those terminals on a 2nd workspace. This can me done by right clicking on the terminal and clicking "Move to another workspace".

Answer (score 0):

First, consider switching to [ubuntu classic desktop](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/08/return-to-ubuntu-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-11-10/).  In clasic desktop you can move and resize windows like in um, windows, and then have multiple terminals visible at once.

Second, consider creating new terminals in the one terminal window.  This can be done with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Third, alhough not much more useful for your purposes than the previous suggestion, have a look at [screen(1)](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), which is old, featureful, and no longer maintained, or tmux(1), which is still maintained.  Either one can be run from a terminal.  Both are installable from [Software Center](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/202571/how_to_install_apps_with_ubuntu_software_center.html) or synaptic.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. how did you get the buttons to render as buttons? I can't figure out the markup

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnome-terminal. The script below will open 3 tabs running the respective commands..

```
tab="--tab"

cmd01="bash -c 'command in 1st terminal';bash"
cmd02="bash -c 'command in 2nd terminal';bash"
cmd03="bash -c 'command in 3rd terminal';bash"

foo=""

foo+=($tab -e "$cmd01")
foo+=($tab -e "$cmd02")
foo+=($tab -e "$cmd03")

gnome-terminal "${foo[@]}"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iterm2+zsh, as it has broadcast mode to multiple windows.